# Twitter OAuth with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, air, adobe

I'm trying to make a Twitter client with Adobe AIR, how can I successfully use OAuth with Javascript? I mean, I've used [jsOauth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) but it seems to lack the oauth_signature somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is you can use the approach that is described in the Facebook developers section dedicated to [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). You want the section that is called "Client-side flow".

In a nutshell they propose that you make an application that will redirect the page it is loaded in to a special URI with it's `app_id` and `backurl` in the query parameters. Once Facebook manages your app's permissions, it will redirect the user back to your page with a special access token in a URI fragment, e.g. `http://example.com/my_app_page/#token=foobar`. This way only your script on the client side can access this token and use it to make requests to the Facebook API.

Answer (score 1):

go have a look at streamie, a twitter client based on node.js. In the source, you can find an extremly good implementation. It's done by cramforce. You find it on github:

https://github.com/cramforce/streamie

Answer (score 1):

jsOAuth uses the Authorization header to pass the OAuth relevant data to the API service.

If you are having issues, by all means email me I'll be happy to look at your code. jsOAuth isn't flawless, I'm fixing bugs as they come up.

Theres a boiler plate for PIN based client auth here: https://gist.github.com/1071227